# JDBC -- trying to create a ATM app when i update 1 user balance all users balance is updated

Tags: db2

I am trying to write a program using JDBC  and DB2, where user can deposit or withdraw from his balance. But is I deposit for one user all users balance is being updated. What should I do so that only one user balance is updated.

Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();

```
   ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery("select * from customers");


 while(rs.next())
   {
        String ename= rs.getString("cos_name");
        String id = rs.getString("cos_pws");

        if(ename.equalsIgnoreCase(uname) && id.equalsIgnoreCase(upass))
        {
            System.out.println("enter 1 deposit");
            System.out.println("enter 2 withdraw");
            System.out.println("enter 3 balance");
            System.out.println("enter 4 for exit");

            int input=scan.nextInt();
            switch(input)
                {

                        case 1: System.out.println("enter deposit amount");
                        double deposit=scan.nextFloat();

                        Double bal=rs.getDouble("cos_balance");
                        if(deposit>0)
                        {
                            bal=bal+deposit;
                            String st2="update customers set cos_balance="+bal;
                            stmt.executeUpdate(st2);


                            System.out.println(bal);
                        }
                        break;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a where clause on your statement so that you only update the selected customers balance e.g. where id = 1